# Docker IPAddress Empty: Cannot Access Container

Tags: java, docker

I built my container as follows:

```
docker build -t microservicedemo/corenlp .
```

Next, I ran it:

```
docker run -P -d --name corenlp microservicedemo/corenlp
```

And docker ps -a shows:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
9e7d92c27e39        microservicedemo/corenlp   "java -Djava.secur..."   4 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        0.0.0.0:32768->8080/tcp   corenlp
```

But I cannot access it at http://localhost:8080 or http://192.168.0.26:8080. When I run `docker inspect 9e7d92c27e39 | grep IPA`, the IP Addresses are NULL or "". Lastly, `DOCKER_HOST` is set as `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`.

I can't figure out how to access the container in a browser or via curl.

Comment: 8080 is the port you use from outside the network. Grab your phone, turn off wifi and turn on mobile data and connect to the IP with the 8080 port. If you're on the network, use :32768 as the port

Answer (score 4):

Look at the output of `docker ps`:

```
PORTS
0.0.0.0:32768->8080/tcp
```

This shows that container's port 8080 was published to host's port No 32768. This is where you should be connecting. You need to send requests to `http://<your docker host ip>:32768` not `http://<your docker host ip>:8080`.

Beware that the `-P` option of `docker run` makes Docker map the all published container ports to random ports on the host, so next time you run the container 8080 might not be mapped to 32768 anymore! You can map the port explicitly if you want to avoid that:

```
docker run -p 8888:8080 -d --name corenlp microservicedemo/corenlp
```

This command will map container's port 8080 to the 8888 port on the Docker host machine (`-p <host port>:<container port>`).

## EDIT

Docker host IP is the IP of the machine [Docker daemon](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/) is running on (the service that hosts images, containers, volumes etc). In case of Linux it's the machine you installed Docker on (by default). In case of Windows and OSX it's the IP of [docker-machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/). `DOCKER_HOST` variable is in no way connected to the IP that Docker publishes the port to. It just defines how the [Docker CLI](https://docs.docker.com/edge/engine/reference/commandline/docker/) (`docker` command) should connect to the above mentioned [Docker daemon](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/) (`dockerd`).

Comment: That's all useful information, thanks. If my DOCKER_HOST is set to unix:///var/run/docker.sock, how do I connect? Or alternatively, how do I know my Docker host IP?